# Accessing JFrame created in main from actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, actionlistener

I've created a frame (mainframe) for my program in the main class which I want to add and remove panels from in order switch between different screens of my program.  The first screen of my program is the login panel which has a start button.  When I press the start button I want to switch to the menu frame.

The removeAll method seems to work fine since the login panel disappears, but nothing appears in its place when I use the add, validate and repaint methods. I have tried to refer explicitly to the mainframe in the actionlistener (i.e. mainframe.add(menu)) but it does not recognise the object.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Main {

    public static JFrame mainframe = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create mainframe to add and remove panels from
        LoginPanel lp = new LoginPanel();
        System.out.println("mainframe created!");

        // Set size of mainframe
        mainframe.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        mainframe.add(lp);

        // Get the size of the screen
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // Determine the new location of the mainframe
        int w = mainframe.getSize().width;
        int h = mainframe.getSize().height;
        int x = (dim.width-w)/2;
        int y = (dim.height-h)/2;

        // Move the mainframe
        mainframe.setLocation(x, y);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

This is my login panel class:

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private final Action action = new SwingAction();

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public LoginPanel() {

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String username = usernameField.getText();
                String password = new String (passwordField.getPassword());

                Login login = new Login();
                boolean Correct = login.isCorrect(username, password);
                **if (Correct == true){
                    removeAll();
                    Menu menu = new Menu();
                    add(menu);
                    validate();  
                    repaint();
                    setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
                    System.out.println("Attempted to start menu!");
                }**
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setAction(action);
        btnLogin.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }});

}
```

Comment: can you please your code in the http://sscce.org/ form

Comment: My random guess if that you are adding to a nested panel that you've removed. That or some other mistake with which panel you are adding to.

Comment: On quite a basic level, I am wondering why a JFrame made public static in my main class cannot be resolved in another class :S - any ideas? @mKorbel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to add and remove panels from in order switch between different screens of my program

Sounds like you should be using a [Card Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: I solved it!  What I did was reference the class in which the frame was made so: Main.mainframe.  Then in the actionlistener section I created a container and used that as a more convenient method of referencing it, like this:  

Container content = Main.mainframe.getContent();
content.removeAll(); etc

Answer (score 1):

Define `mainframe` as a class field:

```
private JFrame mainframe;
```